# How to delete a NativeScript ImageAsset created with nativescript-camera?

Tags: angular, nativescript

```
import { takePicture, CameraOptions } from "nativescript-camera";
```

The `CameraOptions` allows `saveToGallery` to be set to `false`.
However an image is stored on my Android device in Internal Storage > Android > data > org.nativescript.appname > files when I use `takePicture` to create an `ImageAsset`. Console output for the asset `(asset.android)` is:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.nativescript.HelloWorld/files/NSIMG_20180430_131826.jpg
```

I use `imageSource.ImageSource().fromAsset` and `imageSource.ImageSource.saveToFile` to persist the image in some known location and now I would like to **delete** the source file `NSIMG_20180430_131826.jpg` completely from my device.

Can anyone please assist?

Comment: theres a known bug that `saveToGallery` on some phones cant be set so it defaults to true, the github issue is [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-camera/issues/86)

Comment: @mast3rd3mon the file does not appear in "the gallery" (along with other pictures taken with the device) but it is saved in a folder local to the app. The problem is I can't programmaticaly "see" this local folder and also I am not able to delete a file using an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
try {
    //get file
    const path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.nativescript.HelloWorld/files/NSIMG_20180430_131826.jpg";

    const pathArray = path.split('/');
    //get file name
    const fileToRemovePath = pathArray[pathArray.length - 1];
    //remove the file, try adding 'files' as a folder name
    let folder = fs.knownFolders.currentApp().getFolder("yourfoldernamewhereyoucopied");
    const fileToRemove = folder.getFile(fileToRemovePath);
    if(fileToRemove) {
        //delete it
        await fileToRemove.remove();
    }
} catch (e) {
    //dialogs.alert('Couldnot delete the file');
}
```

and you will need import `fs` too:

```
import * as fs from "file-system";
```